# Implementing Voice recorder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, voice

I've created a new view called 'record' this records the users voice. However once the user goes to a different view I want it so the recording doesnt stop and carries on recording their voice. But once I go to another view the recording stops.

How do I make it so its still running after the user has gone into another view?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So you need the record related object to be owned by something other than a view controller, like the app delegate.

Comment: make it an instance variable of the app delegate and initializer it there, for example.  Or create a singleton class that contains the recorder object and provides the functions on it you need (record, pause, rewind, save, etc).